# How to destructure a function argument?

Tags: clojure

`(map (fn [x y] (do-work x y)) {:a 1 :b 2})` won't work because `map` expected a function with one argument. I had to do `(map (fn [x] (let [[p q] x] (do-work p q))) {:a 1 :b 2})` where `let` was to destructure the key value pair. Is there a way to let `fn` destructure the argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(fn [[x y]] ...)` It should work.

Comment: Oh that's so intuitive! Thank you!